# How do I join values from multiple rows in 1 cell with an Excel function?

Tags: excel, function, indexing, match

I'm having troubles joining data from multiple rows into 1 cell in Excel.

So, I've got 2 sheets. The sheet names are 'Data1' and 'Data2'.

The simplyfied layout of the table on Data1: (column headers)

`Number | ID`

The simplyfied layout of the table on Data2: (column headers)

`ID | x | Number`

> What am I trying to do here?
>
> As data is automatically gathered via a TFS query on Data2, I'm trying to fill in the right ID in the `ID` column on Data1.
>   I do this by using the Index/Match funtion.

```
=INDEX(Data2!A:C;MATCH([@[Number]];Data2!C:C;0);1)
```

> However, this returns only the first found value. So if Number 111 is found 4 times in the table on Data2, it'll only return the ID value off the first row of the table on Data2.
>
> If I change the function to: (notice the +1 for the next row)

```
=INDEX(Data2!A:C;MATCH([@[Number]];Data2!C:C;0);1)& ", " & INDEX(Data2!A:C;MATCH([@[Number]];Data2!C:C;0)+1;1)
```

> This will return the second ID aswell, but then again, I'd have to specify +2 and +3 also to get all results AND if I specify +5 when there are only 2 ID's for the Number, it'll still get ID's from other numbers..

I'd love to hear your feedback on how to solve this. Maybe with a count function?

Best regards,

Mati